# Автозаполнение поля со списком

Tags: sql, delphi, access

Всем добра.
Есть две таблицы (на самом деле их много, но проблемы сейчас именно с ними): Одна таблица собирает определенные поля с других таблиц, и в ней уже есть поля в выпадающим списком. Проблема в том, что нужно чтобы при заполнении данных в этих отдельных таблицах, далее они автоматически заполнялись уже в собирательной таблице
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляю значения в поле "объект" через DBEdit, там же потом делаю проверку на повторяющиеся значения и сохраняю таблицу. Потом на кнопке "сохранить" попытался сделать добавление текста из Dbedit в поле из собирательной таблицы

```
if Form4.Query_Object.Modified then Form4.Query_Naimenovanie.FieldByName('Объект').AsString := Form4.Edit1.Text;
```

но это и так понятно, что не сработает, так как там тип данных числовой, но что-то никак не соображу как можно осуществить это.

Как это выглядит на форме в дельфи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. я сначала добавляю данные в DBEdit для объекта, потом жму кнопку сохранить, а потом мне нужно выбрать этот объект в DBLookUpCombobox'e, но уже для таблицы "Наименование". Как мне избавиться от этого комбобокса, чтобы можно было просто один раз написать в DBEdit - и он добавит эти введенные данные сразу в две таблицы.

Comment: т. е. нужно чтобы вместо текста подставлялся код поля? Это lookupComboBox, например.

Comment: Не совсем. Если я поставлю Lookupcombobox, то мне придется сначала ввести данные в DBEdit, а потом снова выбрать те же данные в Lookupcombobox, что и так записал уже в DBEdit. Как раз таки хочу избавиться от этого действия, чтобы один раз только добавить данные в DBEdit чтобы он записал данные в таблицу "Объект", сохранил таблицу, и плюс добавил уже эти сохраненные данные в собирательной таблице "Наименование"

Comment: т.е. вы хотите занести новые данные в справочник Объект. А потом использовать из при заполнении таблицы Наименование?

Comment: Да, но не заполнять таблицу "Наименование" вручную, а автоматом с помощью команды (которую, к сожалению, не знаю).Т.е. я с помощью DBEdit'a добавляю данные в таблицу "Объект" и сохраняю. А с таблицей "Наименование", нужна лишь команда на заполнения поля "Объект"

Comment: Т.е. нужна команда что-то вроде этого: if Form4.Query_Object.Modified(*т.е это уже после добавления новых данных в таблицу Объект*)  then Form4.Query_Naimenovanie. - вот тут прописать что-то чтобы он просто добавил туда код поля из конца списка, потому что новые данные записываются в конец списка

Comment: Это не DBEdit. Вы в Аксессе заполняете таблицы напрямую. Добавляйте сразу в две

Comment: нет, в акссесе это все работает, могу все везде выбирать. Но мне это нужно в дельфи чтобы работало.Думаю, может через костыль LookUpCombobox сделать что-то типа такого if Form4.Query_obj.Modified then Form4.DBLookupComboBox4.Text:=Form4.DBEdit1.Text; а сам Lookupcombobox сделать невидимым

Comment: Событие afterInsert Для dataset связанного с таблицей http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DBClient_TClientDataSet_BeforeInsert.html

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос, думаю яснее суть вопроса стал.

Comment: "потом жму кнопку сохранить" сохраняйте сразу в две таблицы.

Comment: Вот в этом и вопрос весь. Я не знаю как сохранить данные из DBEdit во вторую таблицу, потому что вторая таблица собирательная, как видно из первого скриншота, она содержит лишь внешние ключи основных таблиц и их наименование.

Comment: Ну как-то в одну таблицу вы записываете. Также пишите и во вторую. Если кнопка сохранить у вас на DBNavigator  то у него есть событие onInsert

Answer (score 0):

Создайте для первой таблицы триггер, срабатывающий на добавление новой записи (after insert), который будет добавлять то, что вам нужно в другую таблицу.